# Getting audio hiss out of my project

Tags: audio, adc, dac, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm trying to build a small audio toy for my daughter. I am using a Raspberry Pi Pico and the C SDK. I am able to successfully play a pre-recorded WAV file stored as a C header file using the DAC and speaker. However, when I record myself speaking through the microphone, and then play it back over the speaker through the DAC, there is a noticeable background hiss.

I have the microphone running off separate battery power and that has not made a difference.

I do not hear a background hiss when I play the pre-recorded WAV file through the DAC.

What am I missing?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: It's either the mic preamp or the ADC. Try grounding the ADC input to see how much of the noise disappears.

Comment: Also, the Pi Pico ADC [doesn't seem to be very good](https://pico-adc.markomo.me/).

Comment: If I ground the ADC, much of the noise disappears. I can hear a very faint amount but it is much reduced. As an aside, if I had to pick a micro with a good ADC for this project, what would it be?

Comment: I think I would instead consider switching to a [MEMS microphone](https://www.cdiweb.com/products/detail/mmict390200012-tdk-invensense/672362/) that outputs a digital signal directly.

Comment: The datasheet of the MAX4466 preamp has the highest noise level of any opamp I have ever seen. It is 80 and an OPA134 low noise opamp is 8. Are you using a fairly high quality electret microphone?

Comment: Good question. I’m not really sure how to judge quality of the microphone as I’m very new to all of this yet! Here is the link and I would appreciate any feedback! https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/CMA-4544PF-W.pdf

Comment: I suspect that the mic output may be too low for the ADC so you're turbine up the output volume to compensate and this is boosting the noise too. You need apre-amplifier.